# What is happening when button was clicked in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, drop-down-menu

I'm new to php, I'm developing a web application using php. There is a selectbox and button. When i select a value from that 'Quantity' select box it should change the Total value accordingly. But the change is happening only after click the 'checkout' button why it is happening like that? Even i press the 'F5' button, it is not changing. only when i press the button. Please help me.

Here is the image : [image]

Select box code and total value changing code;

```
echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td width = '55%'>";
            echo $NAME[$i];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td width = '15%'>";
            echo $PRICE[$i];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td width = '15%' align = 'center'>";
            echo "<select name='leDate1' class='textBox' id='leDate1' onchange='getvalue(this.value)'>";

                                $id = $_SESSION['ItemId'];
                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT Quantity FROM itemcategory WHERE ItemId = '$id'");

                                $quantity = "";
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                                {
                                    $quantity = $row['Quantity'];
                                }
                                $title = $_SESSION['selected_option'];
                                echo "<option selected=\"true\" style=\"display:none;\">$title</option>";

                                for($j = 1; $j <= $quantity; $j++){
                                    echo "<option value=\"$j\">$j</option>";
                                }

                            echo "</select>";

            echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td width = '15%'>";
            echo $PRICE[$i]*$_SESSION['selected_option'];
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>";
```

Using this i get selected value from selectbox:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['leDate1'])) {
        $_SESSION['selected_option'] = $_POST["leDate1"];
    }
```

**NOTE :**
Here is the code to achieve the above question :

```
$FormName = "form2";                                
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'function run(){';
echo 'document.'.$FormName.'.submit();';
echo '}';
echo '</script>';
```

Comment: No one can answer your question unless you post your code

Comment: Seriously? Are you expecting an 'abracadabra..here's where you went wrong!'?

Comment: You need to javascript to perform what u wish (I think), read about the difference between client side code and server side code

Comment: If you want to change the values on changing selectbox you have to learn AJAX

Comment: seems like you attached code to button click event, and not select change event.

Comment: you have a general missunderstanding of the concepts involved. you have to difference on what happens on the client and what happens on the server. for your current problem this is solvable just with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the change is happening only after click the 'checkout' button why it is happening like that?

1. The submit button will submit the form.
2. The process of submitting the form will take all the user input from the form and use it to construct an HTTP request.
3. The web server and the PHP will process that HTTP request and generate a response.
4. The response will be sent to the browser.
5. The browser will then render it.

> Even i press the 'F5' button, it is not changing.

That will cause the browser to repeat the *last* request instead of creating a new one with the new user input.

> When i select a value from that 'Quantity' select box it should change the Total value accordingly.

Then you need to use JavaScript to either:

- Duplicate the functionality of the PHP when the user input changes
- Submit the form when the user input changes
- Construct an HTTP request to be sent in the background (e.g. with XMLHttpRequest) and manipulate the DOM to insert the data in the response.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've achieved my question through javascript.